# What is wrong with the code? First code example from Horstmann book

Tags: java, exception, stream, classnotfoundexception

I copied the code example from Horstmann book(Volume2) and don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you help me? I tried to delete IOException, but it raises another problem

```
package streams;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("text.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\PL+"));

    long count = 0;
    for(String w : words)
    {
        if (w.length() > 12) count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);

    count = words.stream().filter(w -> w.length() > 12).count();
    System.out.println(count);

    count = words.parallelStream().filter(w -> w.length() > 12).count();
    System.out.println(count);
}

}
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVOZ.png)

[image]

Comment: Please keep in mind that it's always better to post your error messages as code-formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a class called Hello when you were creating a new java class? The error is clearing stating that it cannot find your class, and therefore throwing the error. Try recreating another java project with a default package and just create a new hello class in that default package. Run a simple println and see if that works if so then try copying your old code into that new file. Hope this helps :)

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaTKm.png

Comment: this worked fine for me when I ran it in eclipse :/

Comment: I see in your screenshot that you have highlighted the Hello.class file which is not going to run, you have to run the Hello file that is in the src folder

Comment: I tried but result is the same and I use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: try recreating another java project with a default package and just create a new hello class in that default package. Run a simple println and see if that works if so then try copying your old code into that new file

Comment: I did it and surprisingly it works. Why it can happen? Can it be caused by package?

Comment: It was an issue in your class paths. Who knows it happened to me a lot when I was following code examples. Make sure to accept the answer and upvote it :)

Comment: It's always classpath. Closed as a duplicate as this has been answered many times over.

Comment: @EdZ make sure to hit the green check mark